# Why does Bazel's rules_closure downloads platform specific binaries instead of sources?

Tags: tensorflow, compilation, bazel

I noticed on the [rules_closure repository](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure) (used by tensorflow when building it with `//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`) that there are rules to build some dependencies like [nodejs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f48673b5054b474fa1e51823edd075088cd16d5f/tensorflow/workspace.bzl#L678) and [protoc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/blob/dec425a4ff3faf09a56c85d082e4eed05d8ce38f/closure/repositories.bzl#L695) through the `filegroup_external` interface.

Why is the reason for not building it from scratch like other dependencies?

I ask because this approach compromises portability, as it needs to list the binaries for each platform that tries to build tensorflow (and it is even worse when there is no binary-ready for your platform).

Comment: I don't know, but [@jart](https://github.com/jart) commits in that repo often so maybe she knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This build configuration works deterministically, out of the box, with no systems dependencies, on recent Linux/Mac/Windows systems with Intel CPUs, and incurs no additional build latency. Our goal has been to optimize for the best build experience, for what's in our support matrix. I agree with you that an escape hatch should exist for other systems. Feel free to open an issue with the rules_closure project and CC: @jart so we can discuss more how to solve that.